# Organize IDB tables in subfolders in MySQL data folder

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-workbench

I can't seem to find the answer elsewhere, and i apologize if the question has been done before, but is it a way to force a MySQL server (community edition) to organize the idb files into subfolders ?

Currently, all the files are located into the data in programData (for Windows). I have 1 table (1 idb file) per week, but i'd like them to be automatically organized by year or month of creation. This to avoid having a folder with +1000 and ease up maintenance.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Don't create one table per week, I guess. Why do you care about "maintenance" of files that are maintained by MySQL?

Comment: *I have 1 table (1 idb file) per week* This is bad idea. One table for all data partitioned by the date seems to be more useful solution. Moreover, the partitions may occupy a lot of tablespaces posessed in different directories and even different volumes, and the partition/tablespace may be discarded (from actual table) and imported (into archive table) without data loss.

Comment: @mustaccio I need to make an off-site backup with an unreliable connection. 1 week keeps the process manageable.

Comment: @Akina The data are time-series. All variables are stored in the same table (which itself has a date identifier). As Windows behaves "ugly" when browsing through a folder with a lot of files, the idea was just to have a folder with month or year folders.

Comment: A typical X-Y Problem™. Instead of asking if you could tell MySQL how to manage its files, you probably should have asked how to set up an offsite backup with an unreliable connection (for which the answer is probably [rsync](https://superuser.com/questions/300263/how-to-use-rsync-from-windows-pc-to-remote-linux-server) or [rclone](https://rclone.org/). Windows behaviour is irrelevant since you don't need to go "browsing through a folder with a lot of files".

Comment: @mustaccio Thanks for your response !  Indeed I should look upon using those tools you mention to solve my main issue (although the issue remains). Local operators other than us can browse the files from time  to time if an intervention on site is needed.  I agree that we can solve the problem by looking one step above and applying corrections a la Kobayashi Maru, but if we are stuck at Y it is interesting at least intellectually to see what could be the action even if it  is far from the ideal. Anywow, what I'm getting from the interaction is that it is not possible to do the subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple tables and is bad for maintenance and code and MySQL.  You should *not* be touching .ibd files in the file system.  There is nothing you can do with the files that would not risk damaging the data.

Furthermore having one-table-per-week (or whatever) is a bad schema design.  That discussion has been had repeatedly on this forum as well as StackOverflow.

The alternative is `PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(...))` and explicitly (say, weekly) `DROP` (if you need to purge) and `REORGANIZE` to create a new partition.

Perhaps the *only* advantage of using `PARTITIONing` for a time-series is the efficiency of deleting old data via `DROP PARTITION`.  I discuss this, and more, in [*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

OK, for your desire to efficiently migrate a week's data to somewhere else, see "transportable tablespaces" for turning a `PARTITION` into a `TABLE`, and then moving it to another machine.  There, you could re-hook it up to a partitioned table.